# How to build hotchocolate with BFF?

Tags: hotchocolate

We use BFF to combine data from different microservices service, can I integrate hotchocolate to work with our API with filtering/soring/pagination?

by my understanding hotchocolate not contain get primary data from different sources and it should return everything to work with it. Seems dataloader can fetch additional fields what is missed in primary set.

BFF(graphql) resolve => getFullList => service 1(filterModel,sortModel, paginationModel)

can I somehow extract to parameters filterModel,sortModel, paginationModel from graphql request using hotchocolate?

I tried to work with full sync entities and pull everything from EntityFramework it works perfectly, but our team is not wanting to do this, because big cost of support.